# Show that $\sum a(n)/\log n$ converges if and only if $\sum a(p)$ converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, convergence-divergence, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

I am studying analytic number theory at the time and I came across with this. I was wondering if there is a somehow smart way to prove the following without using prime number theorem(but probably use some results for approximation of the primes by $n\log n$ or something like that, maybe approximation of $π(x)$ by $x/\log x$ or something like these results which are usually proven just before the prime number theorem) and without any summation formula:

Let $a(n)$ be a nonincreasing sequence of positive numbers. Show that $\sum a(p)$   -sum over all primes- converges if and only if $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a(n)/\log n$ converges.

I have seen 2 questions here about this where they use prime number theorem and summation formulas, but I have a strong feeling that it can be proven without these, I have tried it but nothing seems to work out well. My idea is to work somehow like proving the Cauchy condensation theorem for series and maybe use somehow the fact that there are constants $a$, $b$ positive such that $an\log n<p(n)<bn\log n$ for all $n$ from some $N$ and after -$p(n)$ is the $n$th prime. Or maybe the fact that $(1/6)n/\log n<π(n)<6n/\log n$ for all $n=2,3,...$, or maybe something like that. Any help or ideas whould be much appreciated.

Comment: I think it should be $\sum a(n)/\log n$ instead

Comment: yes you are right im editing it

Comment: Do you mean $\sum\limits_{p\textrm{ prime}} a_p$ and $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} a_n/\log n$ ?

Comment: yes, that is  it

Comment: The "content" of the proof is that the number of primes up to $X$ is approximately $X / \log X$. Any approach must use this somewhere. Note that this is slightly weaker than the Prime Number Theorem --- the upper bound $2X / \log X$ (as known by Chebyshev, for instance) would also work. I note also that these bounds are roughly equivalent to the $n$th prime being approximately $n \log n$, as you seem to want to use.

Comment: yes i get it, thats my thought too, to use something like that approximations but not entirely the prime number theorem, but i find it a bit hard to put it all together, any specific ideas?

Comment: The tool you want to use is partial summation, which will allow you to invoke Chebyshev's bounds for $\pi(x)$. One source for this tool is Appendix A of Montgomery/Vaughan's _Multiplicative Number Theory. I_.

Comment: yeah, i get it until there, but i dont find a particular way to go on, do you see something specific maybe?

Comment: @tongyang2357 What Greg Martin suggests is the standard procedure in analytic number theory. IMO it's specific enough.

Comment: What I want , to say is that I know that this can be solved using partial summation and prime number theorem. It just seems to me that there is a smart way to solve this without using prime number theorem, but just some approximations of the prime numbers or π(x)) by nlnn or n/lnn respectively, or to use some approximation theorem or something in that sense. It also seems that there is a smart way to solve this maybe without even summation formlas, just bounding the partial sums of the two series , the one from the other somehow, just like cauchy condensation criterion if u know.

Comment: If you have something specific in mind like what i mentioned about bounding the partial sums of the two series, the one from the other and reversely , let me know, thats why i am posting the question. a whole book is a lot to search in. i also have apostol's book, which is probably the most famous in analytic number theory. the exercise is from another book, not even apostol.

Comment: @Greg Martin is there something that you see about partial summation and chebychev bounds? because i have tried and i cant get it all together.

Comment: No, as I said, this uses entirely the PNT and a summation formula, I am looking for a way to prove this differently. Look in the upper comments.

Comment: @tongyang2357 You can just replace PNT with Chebyshev bounds in that answer to get what you want.

Comment: yes ok, but you think we cant get the result somehow else without summation formulas?